# Convert logical operators from a list

Tags: python

I have a list that contains the following values `list =  ["Not, "True, "AND", False]` and I would like to get the value that this would return. But I cant convert a string `"AND"` in a list to Boolean `and` though its not allowed, and I cant figure out a way that would do something like `x = not list[1] and list[3]` .

Comment: You can check if `string == "AND"` or `string == "OR"`

Comment: Do you mean you only want to get the boolean values? If so you can use `[x for x in a if isinstance(x,bool)]`, `a` is the name of the list

Comment: It is not clear what else would need to be supported. It is also not clear what you tried so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: This is unclear. It reads like an under-specified homework problem for which no effort has been shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really not clear what you're trying to do or how to apply it but to the original question where:

```
l = ['True', 'AND', 'False']
```

if coverted, this would be:

```
True and False
```

output:

```
False
```

to do this, you can join the list and eval it:

```
eval(' '.join([x if x.istitle() else x.lower() for x in l]))
```

output:

```
False
```

Comment: Darren Christopher's answer is also useful for handling different capitalization combinations and case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`. As per the docstring:

> Evaluate the given source in the context of globals and locals.
>
> The source may be a string representing a Python expression or a code
>   object as returned by compile().

To handle case sensitivity, as `python` operators such as `not`, `and`, and `or` are lower case and `boolean` is capitalize, you can use the condition as follows:

```
eval(" ".join([x.lower() 
               if (x.lower() != "true") and (x.lower() != "false") 
               else x.capitalize() 
               for x in list]))
```

e.g.

```
In [2]: list = ["NOT", "true", "And", "FALSE"]

In [3]: eval(" ".join([x.lower() if (x.lower() != "true") and (x.lower() != "false") else x.capitalize() for x in list
   ...: ]))
Out[3]: False
```